# Location of visual studio include paths

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

What is the complete directory of the visual studio include paths ? For example, they are listed as

```
$(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);
```

under VC+ Directories - Include Directories. But where is VC_IncludePath ? I tried looking up my environment variables on powershell but there was no listing of those paths.

Comment: They don't have anything to do with PowerShell, they are defined either in the Properties sheet of the Project or derived from Visual Studio defaults (Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions), depending on the version of Visual Studio and type of project

Comment: But I can't find the absolute path to it. I want to use #include <png++/png.hpp> but i don't know where I should place png++ folder